# Fastest and simplest way to output Folders Recursion as tree

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

Is there a better way(faster) to do the same thing?If there is a lot of folders.
I know a little about algorithms,I hope someone can give me a better algorithm for this.

I do the work using the code as follow:

```
        private static void ShowAllFoldersUnder(string path, int indent)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                    != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                {
                    foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "{0}{1}", new string(' ', indent), Path.GetFileName(folder));
                        ShowAllFoldersUnder(folder, indent + 2);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
            }    
        }
```

**Output sample result**

```
CompositeUI
  BuilderStrategies
  Collections
  Commands
  Configuration
    Xsd
  EventBroker
  Instrumentation
  obj
    Debug
      TempPE
  Properties
  Services
  SmartParts
  UIElements
  Utility
  Visualizer
```

Comment: Used this code lots of times.   It is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

[EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) could be faster because it does not have to allocate an array of folder names as `GetDirectories` does.